# Using Stokes' Theorem to calculate area

Tags: calculus, parametrization, stokes-theorem

Suppose $C$ is a closed curve parametrised by $x=\cos(2t)$ and $y=t\sin(t)$.

Using Stokes' Theorem, I calculate the result is $0$. But the answer is $\frac{32}9$. What is going wrong?
Here is my caculation:
$ \int_C x dy =\int_{0}^{2\pi} cos(2t)(tcos(t)+sin(t)) dt =0$

Comment: Can you show us your calculation?

Comment: @eranreches  caculation has been add. Please check

Comment: The two lobes of the curve have different orientations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the curve with $\theta=0\rightarrow\theta=\pi$ in clock-wised and with $\theta=\pi\rightarrow\theta=2\pi$ is anti clock-wised. So if you do all the integration anti clock-wised as you should, you get

$$\iint_{\rm D}{\rm d}x{\rm d}y=\int_{\partial\rm D}x{\rm d}y=\\=-\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos\left(2t\right)\left(t\cos t+\sin t\right){\rm d}t+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\cos\left(2t\right)\left(t\cos t+\sin t\right){\rm d}t=\frac{32}{9}$$

as needed.